# TypeError: data.map is not a function i am getting an error while api call and an error called id is not defined

Tags: reactjs

i want to navigate to other page while clicking on the button and while clicking the button i also have to call an api.but its not working can anyone tell me whats the problem
[its the api link] [1]: https://api.tvmaze.com/shows/$%7Bid%7D its my contact component

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export const Contact = () => {
  const url = `https://api.tvmaze.com/shows/${id}`;

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(url).then((json) => setData(json.data));
  }, []);

  const renderTable = () => {
    return data.map((user, i) => {
     return (
     <tr key={i}>
      <td>{user.show?.name}</td>
      <td>{user.show?.language}</td>
      <td>{user.show?.genres}</td>
      <td>{user.show?.runtime}</td>
      <td>{user.show?.premiered}</td>
      <td>{user.show?.rating?.average}</td>
      <td>{user.show?.network?.country?.name}</td>
      <td>
        <img src={user?.show?.image?.medium} alt="poster" />
      </td>
    </tr>
      );
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <table className=" table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">language</th>
            <th scope="col">genres</th>
            <th scope="col">runtime</th>
            <th scope="col">premiered</th>
            <th scope="col">Rating</th>
            <th scope="col">country name</th>
            <th scope="col">image</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{renderTable()}</tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Please try replacing: `data.map((user, i) =>` with `data && Array.isArray(data) && data.length > 0 && data.map((user, i) =>` and let us know the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Here You can use this , No Error will occured

```
  const renderTable = () => {
   return data && data.length > 0 &&  data.map((user, i) => {
    return (
    <tr key={i}>
     <td>{user.show?.name}</td>
     <td>{user.show?.language}</td>
     <td>{user.show?.genres}</td>
     <td>{user.show?.runtime}</td>
     <td>{user.show?.premiered}</td>
     <td>{user.show?.rating?.average}</td>
     <td>{user.show?.network?.country?.name}</td>
     <td>
      <img src={user?.show?.image?.medium} alt="poster" />
    </td>
 </tr>
   );
 });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in api and also the id here

> const url = `https://api.tvmaze.com/shows/${id}

where have you declared the id ? and to make sure that the data is coming fine before using it first console.log() the response data and see what you get and open the network tab to see the reason of the error clearly